# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN to speed up query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone tell me how do I write the following SQL:

```
SELECT url_source_wp.url 
FROM url_source_wp 
WHERE url_source_wp.id NOT IN (
  SELECT url_done_wp.url_source_wp
  FROM url_done_wp 
  WHERE (url_done_wp.url_group = 4) AND (hash IS NULL)) LIMIT 50;
```

using a join?

I tried:

```
SELECT url_source_wp.url 
FROM url_source_wp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN url_done_wp ON url_source_wp.id = url_done_wp.url_source_wp
WHERE url_done_wp.url_group = 4 AND url_source_wp.hash is NULL LIMIT 50
```

But the reply is not the same.

The problem is that the first SQL is very very slow.

Comment: Slow query usually means lack of (proper) indexes. Add the `CREATE TABLE` statements in your question, so we know what indexes exist. Also the `EXPLAIN` output. Your first query seems fine and well-written.

Comment: Indeed... the null-join ("find a row such that no possible join exists") in WoLpH's answer is usually a better thing than a subquery in MySQL, but given reasonable indexes (eg on `url_group`) and assuming the (independent) subquery results aren't ridiculously enormous, I wouldn't expect it to be *that* slow...

Comment: Subquery can result in milions of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT url_source_wp.url 
FROM url_source_wp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN url_done_wp
    ON url_source_wp.id = url_done_wp.url_source_wp AND url_done_wp.url_group = 4 AND hash IS NULL
WHERE url_done_wp.url_source_wp IS NULL
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just negate the two conditions in the WHERE clause ?

I assume you're trying to get all the url_source_wp records whose id's referenced in the url_done_wp table by the FK url_source_wp which do NOT have url_group = 4 and their hash column is NOT NULL, since you used a subquery with NOT IN.
INNER JOIN should be fine to.

So it should be:

```
SELECT url_source_wp.url 
FROM url_source_wp 
INNER JOIN url_done_wp ON url_source_wp.id = url_done_wp.url_source_wp
WHERE url_done_wp.url_group != 4 AND url_source_wp.hash IS NOT NULL LIMIT 50
```

Comment: This is not the same thing. Original query is "where there is no done URL in group 4", this is "where there is a done URL in some other group than 4".